# Java ternary operator badly evaluating null

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I had a weird situation today while I was writing tests. Basically, I had a class with data. Let's say Toy for example, from which we can retrieve a name:

```
public class Toy {

    private String name;

    public Toy(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

And I had an exception, which was working in a way similar to this (e.g. just displaying data about all the objects on which we were working before it went bad); I also included a main for test purpose:

```
public class ToyFactoryException extends Exception {

    public ToyFactoryException(Toy firstToy, Toy secondToy) {
            super("An error occurred when manufacturing: " + 
                       "\nfirstToy: " + firstToy != null ? firstToy.getName() : null + 
                       "\nsecondToy: " + secondToy != null ? secondToy.getName() : null);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            throw new ToyFactoryException(null, new Toy("hi"));

        } catch (ToyFactoryException myException) {

            System.out.println("It should be there.");

        } catch (Exception exception) {

            System.out.println("But it's there instead.");

        }
    }

}
```

As I wrote in the first catch block, the exception should be caught in the ToyFactoryException.

However, in the exception, it's trying to read firstToy.getName() right here: `firstToy != null ? firstToy.getName() : null`

`firstToy != null` should evaluate to false, which means it shouldn't be trying to call `firstToy.getName()` in the first place. When you write it in the reverse order:

```
public ToyFactoryException(Toy firstToy, Toy secondToy) {
    super("An error occurred when manufacturing: " + 
               "\nfirstToy: " + firstToy != null ? null : firstToy.getName() + 
               "\nsecondToy: " + secondToy != null ? secondToy.getName() : null);
        }
```

You realise it reads `null` instead now, which means it's truly reading `firstToy != null` as true.

If you write the main this way instead (the null is the second parameter of the constructor):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        throw new ToyFactoryException(new Toy("hi"), null);

    } catch (ToyFactoryException myException) {

        System.out.println("It should be there.");

    } catch (Exception exception) {

        System.out.println("But it's there instead.");

    }
}
```

It works properly, despite the secondToy ternary condition being written the same way as the firstToy ternary.

Why is the ternary condition on firstToy not evaluating null properly?

Comment: You should put parentheses around your conditional expression.

Comment: I wish I had more feedback whenever I get a downvote. Not knowing what I did wrong is stressing me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put parentheses around your conditional expression.

This:

```
"string " + firstToy != null ? firstToy.getName() : null
```

means this:

```
("string " + firstToy) != null ? firstToy.getName() : null
```

You need this:

```
"string " + (firstToy != null ? firstToy.getName() : null)
```

Comment: Ah, I see why it does that now. Still, I find it weird how it behaves differently between firstToy and secondToy though.